# Using OpenSSL 1.1.x, how to indicate deallocation of STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) items after invoking a function such as sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free()?

Tags: openssl

While migrating applications from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to OpenSSL 1.1.x I've encountered an issue where I cannot find a method to "nullify" STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) pointers in order to indicate the associated item has been deallocated.

For example, a snippet from my existing application using OpenSSL 1.0.2j looks something like the following:

```
X509 *cert;

// ... init X509 cert here ...

if (cert->cert_info != NULL)
{
    sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free(cert->cert_info->extensions, X509_EXTENSION_free);
    cert->cert_info->extensions = NULL; // indicate extensions stack deallocated
}

// ... do other stuff ...
```

After migration to OpenSSL 1.1.x the above snippet would be something like:

```
X509 *cert;
const STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *certExts; 

// ... init X509 cert here ...

if ((certExts = X509_get0_extensions(cert)) != NULL)  
{   
    sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free(certExts, X509_EXTENSION_free);
    // now, what??
}

// ... do other stuff ...
```

With no inherent OpenSSL 1.1.x method for indicating the deallocation, if the application subsequently dereferences the same item (such as another 'sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free()' call, which checks for NULL) then it would be operating on a pointer to deallocated memory.

Am I missing something, or overthinking this? I'm reluctant to modify OpenSSL source code due to licensing implications.  All comments/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of an equivalent OpenSSL 1.1 mechanism for "nullifying" the certificate extensions stack, the solution I finally arrived at was as follows:

```
while (X509_get_ext_count(cert) > 0)
    X509_EXTENSION_free(X509_delete_ext(cert, 0));
```